# ¿Por qué no funciona mi metodo al llamarlo?

Tags: javascript, javascript-metodo

No comprendo por que mi código no funciona. yo estaba viendo un curso de javascript, copié el código tal cual (ya que no sé por que aún no funciona mi código) y aún sigue sin funcionar. estuve 30 minutos buscando una solución, pero aún no la encuentro

```js
constructor (especie, color, edad){
   this.especie = especie
   this.color = color
   this.edad = edad
   this.info = `hola, soy un ${especie}, tengo ${años} y soy de colo ${color}`
}
}

class Perro extends animal () {
constructor (especie, color,edad, raza){
   super (especie, edad, color)
   this.raza = raza
}
ladrar (){
   alert ("WaW")
}
}

const Perro = new animal("perro", "azul", 5, "dogo argentino");

Perro.ladrar();
```

Comment: Cuando algo no funciona, revisa la consola del navegador, ahí vas a ver mensajes de error y saber qué es lo que falla.

Answer (score 3):

Hay muchos errores en tan poco código:

1. Olvidaste incluir la declaración de clase `Animal` y solo por esto ya no funciona el resto del código. De preferencia, los nombres de clase deben comenzar con mayúscula y las variables con minúscula para poder identificar fácilmente, ayudando a evitar errores o confusiones posteriores
2. Al crear la propiedad `info`, estás usando `años` como variable, pero debe ser `edad`
3. En esta línea `const Perro = new animal(...)`

   - La constante `Perro` sobreescribe la clase definida previamente, por eso es conveniente usar mayúsculas y minúsculas con precaución
   - En vez de instanciar la clase `Animal`, se debe usar `Perro`, de lo contrario, te sobrará un parámetro (`raza`) y el método `ladrar()` no estará disponible.

```js
// Definir clase con mayúscula inicial
class Animal {
    constructor (especie, color, edad) {
        this.especie = especie;
        this.color = color;
        this.edad = edad;
        // edad entre ${} y años como texto normal
        this.info = `hola, soy un ${especie}, tengo ${edad} años y soy de colo ${color}`;
    }
}

class Perro extends Animal {
    constructor (especie, color, edad, raza) {
        super (especie, edad, color);
        this.raza = raza
    }
    ladrar () {
        console.log("WaW");
    }
}

// Crear constante con minúscula inicial e instanciar la clase Perro
const perro = new Perro("perro", "azul", 5, "dogo argentino");

perro.ladrar();
```